# Apply attribute to return value - In F#

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, f#

in C# it is possible to apply an attribute to the return of a method:

```
[return: DynamicAttribute]
public object Xyz() {
  return new ExpandoObject();
}
```

Is this possible in F#?

**Background**:

I would like a method of a library written in F# which will be consumed in a language like C# to return *"dynamic"* from a method. If I look into a similarly defined method compiled from C# it seems like the return type is object and the DynamicAttribute is applied to the return value of the object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, you can apply a similar attribute target for the return value.

```ml
let SomeFunc x : [<return: SomeAttribute>] SomeType =
    SomeOperation x
```

See the table of how to specify attribute targets at the end of [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233179.aspx).

Comment: Yes! returning an object and applying the DynamicAttribute shows up as dynamic in a C# project. Thanks!