# How to make Azure function with return attribute in f#?

Tags: f#, attributes, azure-functions, servicebus

I'm writing an azure function in F#, which is supposed to return multiple servicebus queue items.

According to the Microsoft documentation, this is an examle on how to have servicebus as out parameter in C#.

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusOutput")]
[return: ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
public static string ServiceBusOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input, ILogger log)
{
   log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {input.Text}");
   return input.Text;
}
```

How can i have the equivalent of the "[return...]" in F#?

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467227/apply-attribute-to-return-value-in-f